# C++ Reference to Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, c++

I'm creating a bot that needs to find a variable when webpage loads, and set a variable in the bot equal to the variable on the webpage that is in javascript. I know the variable name, but don't know how to reference if you can all in c++ to set my variable to that variable. It is a simple timer and I need to know how long the bot needs to wait before running the next command, as the webpage blocks if you don't wait for the certain amount of time.

Comment: What operating system and browser or library are you using to get the webpage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some example code would be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether what you are asking is possible or not. Variables defined within javascript (thereby running within the javascript sandbox in an interpreter like V8 for Chrome) are going to be incredibly difficult to access if not impossible.

I am not an expert in "bots" but my guess is you would need to scan the DOM looking for some information or use some kind of inter process communication to communicate a state-change to your bot.

Consider running http or websockets on your bot that can accept communications from the javascript running in your page.